# Running scripts inside multiple node project directories with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

**The Context**

I have one main project which has multiple node projects inside that as subdirectories. each one with their own `node_modules` directories and `package.json` files. I want to have an npm script defined in my main `package.json` files which runs npm scripts from each of those projects concurrently.

**The Code**

My directory structure is like this:

```
main:
  ...
  package.json

  - sub-project-1
    - ...
      package.json
  - sub-project-2
    ...
    package.json
```

Sub-project-1/package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node run foo.js"
}
```

Sub-project-2/package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node run bar.js"
}
```

Main package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "/* Here I want to do something like npm sub-project-1/ start && npm sub-project-2/ start */
}
```

Now, obviously I could copy and paste the commands in `sub-project-1/package.json`'s `start` script and `sub-project-2/package.json`'s start script into a bash script and run that instead. But I want to be able to change those `npm start` scripts without having to manually change the bash script every time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you (`fs`) read those `package.json`s and parse their `"start"` values? If so, you can then run them.

Comment: Did you work out how do do this?  Ideally I'd to have a parent `npm run build` which would `cd` into each child npm project, do an `npm install` and `npm run build`.

Comment: We ended up restructuring the project, so it wasn't needed. If you've found a way, feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not concurrent; however, you *can* change the npm start scripts with this approach.

I should mention also that it's not the world's most scalable approach.  But it's simple, so I thought it might be helpful to share.

Here goes ...

Main package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "cd Sub-project-1 && npm run start && cd ../Sub-project-2 && npm run start && cd ../ && <parent project start script here>"
}
```

With this script, you're just meandering through the sub projects and then coming back up to run the parent project's script.

Answer (score -1):

1.You can also write a python script that parses all the package.jsons of the subdirectories and then generate the master package.json file

2.or You can also write a python script that parses all the package.jsons of the subdirectories and then generate a shellscript where the mater package.json
will call it in the "start".

Comment: Why write a python script when OP is using node? Seems like a poor idea.